# How to write this sql in DetachedCriteria in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

```
select * from Confirmation where (fee + extra) >= 12 ;
```

Hi guys,
I want to know an easy way to get the total of two columns (fee + extra) which may possibly passed inside like :

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Confirmation.class)

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyGe(".....", 12));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Confirmation.class)

criteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("fee + extra",new String(){"fee"},new Type(){Hibernate.Integer}));
```

Not tested, but, you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding bro , i just follow the trace you left and I found:"criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(COST_OF_FUND + CONF_PRICE) >= " + bpsPrice))" which is more flexible and works well;